# Can I copy .git directories from an old server to a new sever that has newer Git version?

Tags: git

We are moving to a new sever.
We have copied all our files (including .git directories) with rsync.
But we have newer Git version on the new sever.
On the old server Git version is 1.7.1 on the new sever Git version is 1.8.3.1

Can we just continue using Git as before?
I tested it and it seems it works OK but I'm not sure is this OK to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: Should be fine. You may as well just try it and see. Just do not delete the original before you have checked the copy on the new version. However, this is no different that a normal upgrade of the git package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work fine. But keep an backup, just in case.